# Chart.js bezier curve discontinuity

Tags: chart.js

Chart.js is very cool!  I have inherited some code that is using it and I find it very easy to work with.

My problem, though, is that I would like to use Bezier curves in my line graph but my data is 'sparse'.  It seems that if the line starts after the 0th dataset then the bezier curve points to infinity:

```
bezierCurve: true
```

[image]

I don't see any way to fix this.  If I turn off the bezier curves the graph is correct but not nearly as cool:

```
bezierCurve: false
```

[image]

Does anyone have a clever solution to this problem?

Comment: How did you manage to make the line skip a few x values, been trying and googling like hell and it is driving me crazy already?

Comment: @Limiter - I only assign elements of dataset[y].data[x] where I have values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug that is actively being worked on in [this GitHub pull request](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/pull/435) "Resolve issues with sparse datasets". One of the remaining issues is "Fix problems with bezier curve splining between points with no value". The PR was last updated a couple weeks ago (July 2014) so hopefully this issue will be resolved soon.